# Need Advice in Reorganizing SVN Repository Structure

Tags: tortoisesvn, repository

I found a lot of questions regarding this topic, but couldn't pluck my specific answer from them, so hopefully this isn't a duplicate.

I am using Tortoise SVN at 1.7 (and Ankh in Visual Studio).  I have this SVN structure now:

Branches
|-Branch 1
|-Branch 2 (etc..)
Code (our trunk)
|-SharedStuff
|-Product #1
|-Product #2
Tags
|-tagged release #1
|-tagged release #2 (etc...)

My problem is that every time I create a branch or tag, I have to make it off of the Code folder.  If I am branching Product #1, I need both the Product #1 folder and the SharedStuff folder.  Likewise for a branch of Product #2...I need its own product code and SharedStuff.

What I would like is to create a branch with just what I need for that product update.

Question #1:  can I reorganize this in a way that will allow what I want?
Question #2:  is there more to branching that I just do not understand...am I missing the point?

**Edit:**
For the sake of more clarity, this is the end result that I am trying to achieve for a given branch.

For instance, when I create a branch for Product #1, I want the end result to be:

Branch_of_Product_#1
|-SharedStuff
|-Product #1

...or when it's Product #2:

Branch_of_Product_#2
|-SharedStuff
|-Product #2

So, ultimately I *always* need SharedStuff, but *only* the Product that is the reason for the branch.

Answer (score 0):

You miss one useful feature in Subversion: externals

If **inside** every products you'll have subdirectory, linked to SharedStuff, you'll tag *only Product* subtree

Comment: That is close, and a feature that you correct in saying I missed.  However, I don't want _just_ the Product, but also the Product and the SharedStuff.  It is the _other_ product that I wish to avoid including.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - with externals you don't include, only *add reference* to some point of external resource

Comment: I added some more detail to the original question.  Is that what the external reference will produce?  We use relative path references between the product code and the shared code, so there must be a physical relationship between the location of each.  It cannot simply "point to it".

Comment: @DonBoitnott - well, see at [this project](https://www.assembla.com/code/subversion-troubleshoot-b/subversion/nodes/trunk?rev=7) trunk on site and with RepoBrowser (or checkout) - this project was|is playground for externals

Comment: @DonBoitnott - you have to reorganize, Product's SharedStuff (copy of SharedStuff from root) will be inside Product dir (in order to easy branch/tag in **one** command)